# Is it possible to use this code (or convert it) with a different jQuery version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version

In my project im jusing jQuery 3.5.1 and this code doesn't work with that version.
My question is, if it is possible to convert this code to be usable with jQuery 3.5.1
This is probably a stupid question but I'm pretty new to jquery...

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        function split( val ) {
          return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
          return split( term ).pop();
        }
     
        $( "#tags" )
          // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
          .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          })
          .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
      } );
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
      <input id="tags" size="50">
    </div>
     
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

This code isn't mine I got it from: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple
I made a JSFiddle with 3.5.1 to show you the error it gives: https://jsfiddle.net/cm3thL0r/

Index:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    include "includes/include.php";
    ?>
    <style>
        a {
            /* Styles for anchors without href */
            cursor:pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Kenniscentrum</title>

</head>
<body>

<!--    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

        <div class="body">

            <div class="w-75 mx-auto mt-3">

                <?php

                echo "<form method='post' id='backToMain' action=''>";
                echo "</form>";


                echo "<form method='post' id='backToSub'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='rubriek' value='".$_POST['rubriek']."'>";
                echo "</form>";

                    if(isset($_POST['rubriek'] , $_POST['subrubriek'])){

                        echo "<a class='text-primary' ";
                        ?>onclick="document.getElementById('backToMain').submit();"<?php
                        echo " >Rubrieken > </a>";


                        echo "<a class='text-primary' ";
                        ?>onclick="document.getElementById('backToSub').submit();"<?php
                        echo " >Sub-Rubrieken > </a>"; echo "Artikel";

                    }
                    else if(isset($_POST['rubriek'])){
                        echo "<a class='text-primary' ";
                        ?>onclick="document.getElementById('backToMain').submit();"<?php
                        echo " >Rubrieken > </a> Sub-Rubrieken";
                    }
                    else if(!isset($_POST['subrubriek'])){
                        echo 'Rubrieken';
                    }
                ?><button class="btn btn-success float-right mr-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalCreate">Nieuw</button>
            </div>

            <table id="example" class="mt-3 w-75 table table-striped table-bordered mx-auto">

                <th>Naam</th>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['rubriek'] , $_POST['subrubriek'])){
                        getAllArtikel();
                    }
                    else if(isset($_POST['rubriek'])){
                        getAllSubRubriek();
                    }
                    else if(!isset($_POST['subrubriek'])){
                        getAllRubriek();
                    }
                ?>

            </table>
        </div>

        <?php
        include "includes/Modals/modal.php";
        include "includes/Modals/modalEdit.php";
        include "includes/Modals/modalEditRubriek.php";
        include "includes/Modals/modalEditSubrubriek.php";
        include "includes/Modals/modalDelete.php";
        include "includes/Modals/modalDeleteRubriek.php";
        include "includes/Modals/modalDeleteSubrubriek.php";
        include "includes/Modals/modalCreate.php";
        ?>

        <script  src="includes/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

includes:

```
    <?php
include "dbconn.php";
include "phpFunctions.php";
?>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Some parts might be dutch sorry about that....

Comment: Yes is possible

Comment: @SimoneRossaini How to do that?

Comment: Simple you need to see which error or deprecated function has your code and traslate with new one.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini it says: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on(...).autocomplete is not a function
    <anonymous>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see all work with jquery 3.5, i just change `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` with cdn of 3.5

```js
$( function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        function split( val ) {
          return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
          return split( term ).pop();
        }
     
        $( "#tags" )
          // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
          .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          })
          .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
      } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
      <input id="tags" size="50">
    </div>
     
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I see that it works, but what exactly did you do?

Comment: _As you can see all work with jquery 3.5, i just change <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> with cdn of 3.5_ 
I wrote it

Comment: I know but what is the cdn of 3.5? Is it a different version?

Comment: the only difference is that it is on a server

Comment: Ok thanks, I still have a problem including it in my project, but I'll try to fix that.

Comment: Yes, but i don't see your code so i can't help you. please flag answer because the question is done

Comment: I know you can't see my code. I'll flag it answered when my code works, because there may be still a problem

Comment: And little question where do you put the jQuery code? in <script> tags or in a different file?

Comment: i prefer different file, so call jquery next call your script for autocomplete. you can just use my code and all work :) if you don't post your code no one can help you

Comment: I'll post my code but its possible that won't help

Comment: I have added my code ( that matters here )

Comment: Does the extra code help? I haven't added the autocomplete in this code because then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229386/discussion-between-niels040-and-simone-rossaini).

Comment: look chat please